# How to create a new sortedset in Redis without clients and lua

Tags: database, lua, redis, nosql

I have a sortedset in redis.

I can get the range result with command ZRANGEBYSCORE.

And I need put this result into a new set. But I don't want to retrieve the result to the client, and put the result back into redis.

I know the Lua script can do this. But it's forbidden in my current environment.

So is there any other idea?

Comment: Nope, looks like you're out of options

Answer (score 0):

Unless you imlement this using a *Lua* script loaded in Redis, there's no available command like `zrangebyscoreandstore` to store results without retrieving them in your application layer.